# Kony Web Application is having Object.wait() on Concurrent Service Calls

Tags: java, websphere, java.util.concurrent, temenos-quantum, dynatrace

While executing a performance test of 150 users using SilkMeter for Kony Web Application, we came across a strange behavior where services are held on wait state on the doFilter method.

The application is running on IBM WebSphere 8.5.10 and web thread is configured as min 50 and max 800. The issue is when we increase the number of users, the wait() method is also increasing in time.
Below is a screen captured from Dynatrace. 
[![Dynatrace report][1]][1]

We tried many methods but couldn't get rid of this wait method. Any suggestions?

Comment: the increasing time taken on Object.wait() is a symptom of other performance problems (e.g. tuning, hardware, fundamental app arch) that is significantly beyond the scope of a stackoverflow question

Comment: What’s the number of threads under Threadpool settings in WAS? We had a similar problem with Kony app and increasing Threadpool count helped.

Comment: min 50 and max 800. But active thread counts is around 20-25 only. When we increase the load, active threads are not increasing much, but wait time is increasing

Comment: @AndyGuibert The App server contains 4 CPUs and 64GB RAM. All tuning has been done but no effect. We had IBM and Kony to support as well but still clueless

Comment: @AndyGuibert Hi Andy, I see that you are a IBM WebSphere developer. Could you please get in touch? We are involving IBM team and still having trouble figuring out the issue.

Comment: Are there any hung threads in the node? Min 50 and Max 800 for database Threadpool ? If you don’t mind can you share a screenshot of your DB thread config from WAS?

Comment: @highhope there are no hung threads. Min and max is for WebContainer Thread pool is 50 and 800. Also DB is 20-50 only..

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of Kony which is tested in 7.3.0 version.
This happens when the Transactions per hour increases. When there are many server hits, due to kdw, we can see a wait time. If this increases beyond, 5 seconds, then it's better to reduce the Transactions and think time of silk meter.
Kony supports 35 requests per sec for 1 CPU and 8 GB memory. Exceeding this would increase wait time as shown in the figure.